# Efetua a operação mas exibe erro no final

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o código abaixo que está me tirando do sério.

Não é possível gente!

```
// JavaScript Document// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("a.excluiFalecimento").click(function() {

      if (confirm('Deseja Excluir esta Nota?') ) {

           $.post ("../_requeridos/excluiFalecimento.php", {

               idFalecimento   : $(this).attr('falecimentoid')

           }, function(retorno){
               alert(retorno)
               if (retorno == "OK") {

                    alert('Excluido com sucesso');
                    location.reload();

                } else {

                    alert("Erro na exclusão");

                }

             }
        );

        return false;

      }

  })


});
```

Tenho 4 arquivos exatamente iguais com exceção apenas dos nomes das variáveis.

Tenho ali um `alert` que está imprimindo **OK**

```
               alert(retorno)
               if (retorno == "OK") {
```

Mas não entra no bloco correto.

E, obviamente não faz o **reload**.

Onde estou errando?

Detalhe, a exclusão está sendo feita normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno do Ajax vem com espaços em branco nas bordas e não apenas a string pura.

Para resolver isso, limpe o retorno com o método `.trim()`, assim é assegurado retornar somente a string `OK` e o `if` irá validar:

```
if (retorno.trim() == "OK") {
   ...
}
```

Ou (menos recomendado) você pode verificar se no retorno possui a string `OK`:

```
if(~retorno.indexOf("OK")){
   ...
}
```

Comment: sim, de fato era isso. Masa porque os outros 3 arquivos idênticos não deram esse problema? Obs.: já olhei o assinatura BOM dele. Não tem. Está como UTF sem BOM

Comment: rs.. não sei dizer, cada caso é de se analisar.

Comment: Por via das dúvidas, nesses casos onde se espera uma string e deseja fazer uma comparação extada no `if`, é bom usar `.trim()`. Ou então você poderia usar `if(~retorno.indexOf("OK")){...}`